# How can I Copy and Paste the form to another object?

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image: Eyes]
Hello, I´m new to blender and want to find out if I can copy the form of the good eye and paste it on to the bad eye.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you can use SHIFT-D to duplicate the good eye, then delete the bad eye. Or simply add a UV Sphere as a whole new eye, eyes are (almost) perfect spheres.

Answer (score 3):

If at any moment you want to change the mesh of an object for another one (here for example you want to switch from the cube to the cone), select the object, go in *Object Data* and in the top dropdown menu (*Browse Mesh Data*) select the mesh you want:

[image]

[image]

Or select the object, shift select the one that you want to copy the mesh from, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> > *Link Object Data*.